# Is 100 Hz really 100 Hz, or is it 99.97Hz

Tags: video

We are trying to check some hardware and our 100Hz video card is running at 99.97Hz.  Maybe this is just the natural speed of the chip and it is called 100Hz.  I would have thought, however, that 100Hz is very slow for a computer and that control would closer to the megahertz.  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: I only have the smart alecky comment to make, that nothing in nature lines up perfectly, so I'm sure it isn't exactly 100hz, or the same every frame. But, I have no idea how close it is.  There is probably a bit of inaccuracy in whatever is measuring the hz as well.

Comment: 100 Hz is _far_ too low for any PC graphics card clock speed from the last couple of decades. Even if the chip is completely idle and clocked down as far as it goes, it should still be running at some tens or hundreds of MHz. I guess 100 Hz could conceivably be the video refresh rate, not the clock speed. But that would still be strange, as refresh rates are almost always multiples of 60 Hz these days.

Comment: 100Hz is far too low for any PC graphics card clock, ever. Formerly PAL countries continue to broadcast at 50Hz though, for the record. So multiples of 50 aren't too surprising.